# XPath selector by class AND index

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p class='foo'>foo</p>
  <p class='foo'>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

How can i select second P tag with class 'foo' by XPath?

Comment: Resolved now. `//div/p[@class="foo"][2]` works in difference from `//p[@class="foo"][2]` Seems like parent object is obligatory

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following expression should do it:

```
//p[@class="foo"][2]
```

---

Edit: The use of `[2]` here selects elements according to their position among their siblings, rather than from among the matched nodes. Since both your tables are the first children of their parent elements, `[1]` will match both of them, while `[2]` will match neither.  If you want the second such element *in the entire document*, you need to put the expression in brackets so that `[2]` applies to the nodeset:

```
(//p[@class="foo"])[2]
(//table[@class="info"])[2]
```

Comment: It not works. `//p[@class="foo"][1`] returns both P tags and `//p[@class="foo"][2]` returns nothing

Comment: Actual code [here](http://pastie.org/private/wjsgjdihrz7dzjbxsjjkg). I try to select second table with class 'info'

Comment: Also [that's what i get](https://img.skitch.com/20111109-eii1yxa4cq156yy9tbm76hp356.png) from Firebug

Comment: `//table[@class="info"][position()=1]` returns both tables too

Comment: But `//div[@id="main"]/div[@class="inner"][2]/table[@class="info"]` works as expected.

Comment: will not work if the class is `<p class="class1 foo">foo</p>`